# How to assign the end of a reference chain?

Tags: c++

For example I have a class:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(const Foo& foo) : father(foo) {}
 private:
  const Foo& father;
};
```

How to assign the `father` field if the object is the top?
I tried `Foo foo(foo);`, but the compiler warn me the foo is uninitialized, I guess the compiler only assign memory to the foo object after all initialization are done, so if I do this way, the `father` will reference to some wild memory address.

So, In this case, how to assign the `father` right if the object is the top?

Comment: *"... if the object is the top"* - what does it mean?

Comment: @vahancho Top of the chain, i.e. a reference bound to an object directly rather than via another reference (which is the case for the rest of the chain)

Comment: Be careful when using the above especially with STL containers like vectors and lists. You are using the copy constructor which can lead to very hard to find bugs because everytime you insert an object into an STL container it will be copied with the copy constructor and in your case, this would overwrite your `father` with a reference to the copied object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a special constructor (and use a tag to distinguish your constructor from the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)):

```
struct father_tag {};

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(const Foo& foo, father_tag) : father(foo) {}
  Foo() : father(*this) {}
 private:
  const Foo& father;
};

// usage:
Foo father;
Foo next(father, father_tag{});
```

or you can use a pointer instead of a reference, leaving it to `nullptr` at the end of the chain. Then you can check with `if (father)` if you are at the end or not:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(Foo const* pfather) : m_pfather(pfather) {}
  Foo() : m_pfather(nullptr) {}
 private:
  Foo const* m_pfather;
};
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but isnt `Foo(const Foo &) ` the signature if the copy contructor? This could lead to very hard to find bugs when using STL containers since when you insert an Object into a container it will be copied and then the `father` would be overwritten.

Comment: @Yastanub You are right, we should probably use a different signature. For the second solution it's clear: Just use a pointer parameter. How would you change the first variant?